# How would you implement a Node JS Authentication System

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication

I am just beginning to learn how to use node JS to make a website. In this website I would like to implement an authentication system. Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Connor

Comment: Way too broad a question for stack overflow.  You don't provide ANY requirements or say anything about what research you did and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://passportjs.org

Generally, the way to go especially to start.

https://beta.freecodecamp.org/en/challenges/advanced-node-and-express/set-up-passport May also help you get started with it